# Listing directories at a given level in Amazon S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, directory

I am storing two million files in an amazon S3 bucket. There is a given root (l1) below, a list of directories under l1 and then each directory contains files. So my bucket will look something like the following

```
l1/a1/file1-1.jpg
l1/a1/file1-2.jpg
l1/a1/... another 500 files
l1/a2/file2-1.jpg
l1/a2/file2-2.jpg
l1/a2/... another 500 files
....

l1/a5000/file5000-1.jpg
```

I would like to list as fast as possible the second level entries, so I would like to get a1, a2, a5000. I do not want to list all the keys, this will take a lot longer.

I am open to using directly the AWS api, however I have played so far with the right_aws gem in ruby http://rdoc.info/projects/rightscale/right_aws

There are at least two APIs in that gem, I tried using bucket.keys() in the S3 module and incrementally_list_bucket() in the S3Interface module. I can set the prefix and delimiter to list all of l1/a1/*, for example, but I cannot figure out how to list just the first level in l1. There is a :common_prefixes entry in the hash returned by incrementally_list_bucket() but in my test sample it is not filled in.

Is this operation possible with the S3 API?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the S3 documentation for the ListBucket operation: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/index.html?SOAPListBucket.html. To obtain a1-a5000 specify prefix="/l1/" delimeter="/". To obtain /l1/a123/* specify prefix="/l1/a123/", delimeter="/". Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Oren,

You are right it is working now. Thanks a lot.

Maybe the test bucket structure I created was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

`right_aws` allows to do this as part of their underlying `S3Interface` class, but you can create your own method for an easier (and nicer) use. Put this at the top of your code:

```
module RightAws
  class S3
    class Bucket
      def common_prefixes(prefix, delimiter = '/')
        common_prefixes = []
        @s3.interface.incrementally_list_bucket(@name, { 'prefix' => prefix, 'delimiter' => delimiter }) do |thislist|          
          common_prefixes += thislist[:common_prefixes]
        end
        common_prefixes
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This adds the `common_prefixes` method to the `RightAws::S3::Bucket` class. Now, instead of calling `mybucket.keys` to fetch the list of keys in your bucket, you can use `mybucket.common_prefixes` to get an array of common prefixes. In your case:

```
mybucket.common_prefixes("l1/")
# => ["l1/a1", "l1/a2", ... "l1/a5000"]
```

I must say I tested it only with a small number of common prefixes; you should check that this works with more than 1000 common prefixes.

Comment: it is amazing that this wasn't built in still, but this saved me a lot of time. thanks.

Comment: I improved it somewhat here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849939/how-to-do-the-equivalent-of-s3cmd-ls-s3-some-bucket-foo-bar-in-ruby/ (it also lists individual files now). Still can't believe that this isn't built into one of the many Ruby S3 gems.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is quite old but I did run into this issue recently and wanted to assert my 2cents...

It is a hassle and a half (it seems) to cleanly list out folders given a path in an S3 bucket.  Most of the current gem wrappers around the S3 API (AWS-SDK official, S3) don't correctly parse the return object (specifically the CommonPrefixes) so it is difficult to get back a list of folders (delimiter nightmares).

Here is a quick fix for those using the S3 gem... Sorry it isn't one size fits all but it's the best I wanted to do.

https://github.com/qoobaa/s3/issues/61

Code snippet:

```
module S3
  class Bucket
    # this method recurses if the response coming back
    # from S3 includes a truncation flag (IsTruncated == 'true')
    # then parses the combined response(s) XML body
    # for CommonPrefixes/Prefix AKA directories
    def directory_list(options = {}, responses = [])
      options = {:delimiter => "/"}.merge(options)
      response = bucket_request(:get, :params => options)

      if is_truncated?(response.body)
        directory_list(options.merge({:marker => next_marker(response.body)}), responses << response.body)
      else
        parse_xml_array(responses + [response.body], options)
      end
    end

    private

    def parse_xml_array(xml_array, options = {}, clean_path = true)
      names = []
      xml_array.each do |xml|
        rexml_document(xml).elements.each("ListBucketResult/CommonPrefixes/Prefix") do |e|
          if clean_path
            names << e.text.gsub((options[:prefix] || ''), '').gsub((options[:delimiter] || ''), '')
          else
            names << e.text
          end
        end
      end
      names
    end

    def next_marker(xml)
      marker = nil
      rexml_document(xml).elements.each("ListBucketResult/NextMarker") {|e| marker ||= e.text }
      if marker.nil?
        raise StandardError
      else
        marker
      end
    end

    def is_truncated?(xml)
      is_truncated = nil
      rexml_document(xml).elements.each("ListBucketResult/IsTruncated") {|e| is_truncated ||= e.text }
      is_truncated == 'true'
    end
  end
end
```