# How to do the equivalent of 's3cmd ls s3://some_bucket/foo/bar' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

How do I do the equivalent of 's3cmd ls s3://some_bucket/foo/bar' in Ruby?

I found the Amazon S3 gem for Ruby and also the Right AWS S3 library, but somehow it's not immediately obvious how to do a simple 'ls' like command on an S3 'folder' like location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Ruby AWS SDK now supports this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/Tree.html

You can also add the following convenience method:

```
class AWS::S3::Bucket
  def ls(path)
    as_tree(:prefix => path).children.select(&:branch?).map(&:prefix)
  end
end
```

Then use it like this:

```
mybucket.ls 'foo/bar' # => ["/foo/bar/dir1/", "/foo/bar/dir2/"]
```

Comment: `select(&:branch?)` will only select `BranchNode` objects ("folders"), whereas `select(&:leaf?)` will return files. If you want to work with all objects in a tree, just use `children` without the `select`.

Answer (score 7):

Using the `aws` gem this should do the trick:

```
s3 = Aws::S3.new(YOUR_ID, YOUR_SECTRET_KEY)
bucket = s3.bucket('some_bucket')
bucket.keys('prefix' => 'foo/bar')
```

Comment: This returns all keys recursively. The command 's3cmd ls s3://some_bucket/foo/bar' only lists the results in the folder 'bar' (even though folders do not really exist on S3).

Comment: Apparently you need delimiter support in AWS-SDK to make it possible to emulate 's3cmd ls'. It seems that this is not possible for the moment.

Answer (score 4):

I found a similar question here: [Listing directories at a given level in Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239700/listing-directories-at-a-given-level-in-amazon-s3)

Based on that I created a method that behaves as much as possible as 's3cmd ls <path>':

```
require 'right_aws'

module RightAws
  class S3
    class Bucket
      def list(prefix, delimiter = '/')
        list = []
        @s3.interface.incrementally_list_bucket(@name, {'prefix' => prefix, 'delimiter' => delimiter}) do |item|
          if item[:contents].empty?
            list << item[:common_prefixes]
          else
            list << item[:contents].map{|n| n[:key]}
          end
        end
        list.flatten
      end
    end
  end
end

s3 = RightAws::S3.new(ID, SECRET_KEY)
bucket = s3.bucket('some_bucket')

puts bucket.list('foo/bar/').inspect
```

Comment: It is now also possible to have 's3cmd ls' like functionality using the official ruby aws-sdk: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/Tree.html

Answer (score 2):

In case some looks for the answer to this question for the aws-sdk version 2, you can very easily do this this way:

```
creds = Aws::SharedCredentials.new(profile_name: 'my_credentials')

s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1',
                                credentials: creds)

response = s3_client.list_objects(bucket: "mybucket",
                                  delimiter: "/")
```

Now, if you do

```
response.common_prefixes
```

It will give you the "Folders" of that particular subdirectory, and if you do

```
response.contents
```

It will have the files of that particular directory

Answer (score 0):

a quick and simple method to list files in a bucket folder using the ruby aws-sdk:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

  s3 = AWS::S3.new
  your_bucket = s3.buckets['bucket_o_files']
  your_bucket.objects.with_prefix('lots/of/files/in/2014/09/03/').each do |file|
    puts file.key
  end
```

Notice the '/' at the end of the key, it is important.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Idea of opening the Bucket class and adding a 'ls' method. 
I would have done it like this...

```
class AWS::S3::Bucket
  def ls(path)
    objects.with_prefix("#{path}").as_tree.children.select(&:leaf?).collect(&:member).collect(&:key)
  end
end

s3 = AWS::S3.new
your_bucket = s3.buckets['bucket_o_files']
your_bucket.ls('lots/of/files/in/2014/09/03/')
```