# Possible algorithm for multithreading listing all keys in a large S3 bucket?

Tags: rest, amazon-s3, concurrent-programming

In S3 buckets containing large numbers of keys, listing keys through the REST api is a painfully slow process since

1. You can only list 1000 keys at a time.
2. The only way to determine the 5001th key (as far as I can tell) is to list the first 1000 keys, list the next based on the next marker in the response, then recurse until you get to 5001.
3. S3 REST api requests are very high latency, a request for 1000 keys generally takes several seconds.

Given that making 100 concurrent key listing REST requests shouldn't slow any individual request down, this process would otherwise be ripe for optimization through parallelization.  But if my algorithm is "stupid" and just splits up the possible key space into pre-defined markers (for instance, '', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ...) it won't really speed up listing keys in a bucket where every key starts with 'images/'

So I'm wondering if anyone really experienced with S3 knows a better way to traverse a bucket's key space OR if anyone has experimented with an adaptive (i.e. "not stupid") algorithm to improve key listing with concurrency.

Comment: Since S3 returns large XML - uncompressed - you will flood your internet connection with only a few requests, depending of course on your connection and the speed of your program.

Comment: I'm going to use the mechanism here by listing the keys at each level and going down the tree with threads.  It might work for you too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239700/listing-directories-at-a-given-level-in-amazon-s3

Comment: @TomAndersen just saw this now 4 years later. I challenge you to saturate an ec2 instance bandwidth (100s of mbps) with S3 bucket list reqs, lol.

Comment: I can saturate the connection -the limit is #of IOPs, which is 5,500 reads per second, across all clients, for a specific prefix. You don't need more than a few tens of aggressive EC2 clients befor they all get 503s and you have to back off. If you are treewalking, take the lit of paths returned, and randomise before diving in to them.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some form of the 'binary search' algorithm would help? EG start with prefixes at '' and 'm' then half way, etc. I think that you would end up getting each key at most twice or so  - you stop calling for more when you have the 'nextmarker' already.

How to pick how many to start with? I think perhaps subdivide at each cycle: launch '' then when those results come back, if the '' results indicate more keys, then launch the 'nextmarker' on that search PLUS a new search half way between 'nextmarker' and 'z'. Repeat. Use a hash like thing to store all the keys once only.

Since all the requests are coming in in different threads, etc you would need locking to add all the keys. Then you have the problem of keeping that lock open enough not to slow stuff down, so it would depend on what language, etc you are using.

You might be able to do it faster if your process is running on an EC2 instance in the same region as the S3 files. Say the files are in USA 'standard'. Then you are in luck, You could use ruby and something like Ironworker to get in there and download all the keys. When its done it could post to your server, or make a file on S3 that is a listing of all keys, or similar. For different regions, or languages you may have to launch your own EC2 instance.

I have found that S3 key listing is much faster on an EC2 instance, as there is lots of bandwidth (which you don't pay for on EC2) for each request. S3 does NOT gzip the responses, which are super fluffy XML, so bandwidth between you and the S3 is critical.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think the binary search approach works any better than just subdividing the theoretical keyspace ahead of time, because if keys are densely clustered under, say, 'images/,' each batch is more or less the same distance from the end of the key space. Certainly requests made from EC2 instances are lower latency/higher throughput, but what I'm really looking for is an algorithm that will optimize any key traversal regardless of such factors beyond its control. I think using prefixes and delimiters to fake a breadth first traversal has promise, but needs more thought.